# Issues with the following json data

Tags: json

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with the following json data, i'm currently using http://jsonlint.com/ to validate it which keeps failing with;

```
Parse error on line 9:
...                    "Question 2" : [   
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

**My code;**

```json
{ "questions" : {
        "Question 1" : [
        { "Q" :"Question" },
        { "A" : "Answer A"  },
        { "B" : "Answer B" },
        { "C" : "Answer C" },
        { "D" : "Answer D" },
        { "Answer" : "C" }
        ] 
        "Question 2" : [
        { "Q" :"Question" },
        { "A" : "Answer A"  },
        { "B" : "Answer B" },
        { "C" : "Answer C" },
        { "D" : "Answer D" },
        { "Answer" : "C" }
        ] 
    }
}";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've forgot a comma!

```
{ "questions" : {
                "Question 1" : [
                { "Q" :"Question" },
                { "A" : "Answer A"  },
                { "B" : "Answer B" },
                { "C" : "Answer C" },
                { "D" : "Answer D" },
                { "Answer" : "C" }
                ],
                "Question 2" : [
                { "Q" :"Question" },
                { "A" : "Answer A"  },
                { "B" : "Answer B" },
                { "C" : "Answer C" },
                { "D" : "Answer D" },
                { "Answer" : "C" }
                ] 
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing the comma between your *Question* keys.

```
{ "questions" : {
                    "Question 1" : [
                    { "Q" :"Question" },
                    { "A" : "Answer A"  },
                    { "B" : "Answer B" },
                    { "C" : "Answer C" },
                    { "D" : "Answer D" },
                    { "Answer" : "C" }
                    ],
                    "Question 2" : [
                    { "Q" :"Question" },
                    { "A" : "Answer A"  },
                    { "B" : "Answer B" },
                    { "C" : "Answer C" },
                    { "D" : "Answer D" },
                    { "Answer" : "C" }
                    ] 
}
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you're missing a comma after the array closes.

```json
JSON = { 
  "questions" : {
      "Question 1" : [
          { "Q" :"Question" },
          { "A" : "Answer A"  },
          { "B" : "Answer B" },
          { "C" : "Answer C" },
          { "D" : "Answer D" },
          { "Answer" : "C" }
      ],// end of Question 1 "this is where you'r missing the comma"
      "Question 2" : [
          { "Q" :"Question" },
          { "A" : "Answer A"  },
          { "B" : "Answer B" },
          { "C" : "Answer C" },
          { "D" : "Answer D" },
          { "Answer" : "C" }
      ] // end of Question 2
  }//end of questions object
}";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Expecting 'EOF', '}', '`,`', ']'**

Between array of Questions, You missed COMMA after "Question 1" as answered by others. Let Plain Object to JSON string mapping be done by REST providers like JAKSON if you're using JERSEY. Otherwise, use other APIs for mapping.

The validation answers it clearly, however where exactly the comma is missing. The very common mistakes experienced are either missing { brace for object, [ bracket for representing arrays or ,(comma) for delimiting array of elements.